# Sum and grouping in MDX query

Tags: ssas, mdx

I need an MDX query to sum data from one column and aggregates data from another by its type. For examply, my current query is:

```
    SELECT 
 { [Measures].[DeclCount], [Measures].[SubCount]} ON COLUMNS, 
 {  (
 [Organization].[OrganizationKey].[OrganizationKey].ALLMEMBERS * 
 [Organization].[Name].[Name].ALLMEMBERS * 
 [Organization].[Need Declaration10].[Need Declaration10].ALLMEMBERS *  
 [DeclType].[DeclarationNumber].[DeclarationNumber].ALLMEMBERS
 )
}  
  ON ROWS
FROM 
(
    SELECT
        DESCENDANTS([Organization].[OrganizationKey].CHILDREN) on COLUMNS
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT ([Organization].[Code].&[0105044397] ON COLUMNS
        FROM [MyCube]
    )
)
```

Current result is:
    Code - Name - Need Declaration10 - DeclType - DeclCount - SubCount
    Code1 - Organization1 - 0 - 1 - NULL - NULL
    Code1 - Organization1 - 1 - 2 - 1 - 2
    Code1 - Organization1 - 1 - 3 - 2 - 2

Desired result is:

```
Code - Name - Sum(Need Declaration10) - SumDeclCount1 - SumSubCount1 - SumDeclCount2 - SumSubCount2 - SumDeclCount3 - SumSubCount3
Code1 - Organization1 - 2 - NULL - NULL - 1 - 2 - 2 -2
```

How can i achieve this with MDX? Thanks for any help.

Edit:
Thanks Frank, it's almost everything I need. 
The last two things are: 
 1. I have 10 different [DeclType].[DeclarationNumber]. Is it possible to modify ([DeclType].[DeclarationNumber].All, Measures.[Sum of Need Declaration10]) to calculate the sum for each of them? 
 2. I need to populate SSRS report with this query. Is it possible to get flattened dataset from this query? Ideal soultion would be set like 
(OrganizationKey, OrganizationName, DeclCount_X, SubCount_X, SumOfNeed_X) 
where X=1..10

Comment: The things you want to sum should be measures. I think you should learn about dimensional modelling first. Then, if the data model is right, the MDX would probably be rather simple.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already stated in the comment, this is more difficult than it should be as `[DeclarationNumber]` is an attribute/hierarchy but not a measure. I hope my workaround below will work, assuming that the `[DeclarationNumber]` only contains integer values. Nevertheless, they have to be converted from String to a numeric type to be able to use them similar to a measure.

The easy part is moving the  moving the `[DeclType].[DeclarationNumber]` to the columns.

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.[Declaration10 numeric] as
            CInt([Organization].[Need Declaration10].CurrentMember.Name)
     MEMBER Measures.[Sum of Need Declaration10] as
            Sum(EXISTING [Organization].[Need Declaration10].[Need Declaration10].Members,
                Measures.[Declaration10 numeric]
            )
SELECT { ( 
           [DeclType].[DeclarationNumber].All,
           Measures.[Sum of Need Declaration10]
       ) }
       +
       (
         [DeclType].[DeclarationNumber].[DeclarationNumber].Members
         *
         {[Measures].[DeclCount], [Measures].[SubCount]}
       )
       ON COLUMNS,

       [Organization].[OrganizationKey].[OrganizationKey].ALLMEMBERS
       * 
       [Organization].[Name].[Name].ALLMEMBERS
       ON ROWS
FROM 
(
    SELECT
        DESCENDANTS([Organization].[OrganizationKey].CHILDREN) on COLUMNS
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT ([Organization].[Code].&[0105044397] ON COLUMNS
        FROM [MyCube]
    )
)
```

As I  do not have access to your cube, there may be some tweaks necessary, be it to syntax or to some logic of the statement.

Comment: Thanks, it's almost everything I need.

Comment: The last two things are:

1. I have 10 different [DeclType].[DeclarationNumber]. Is it possible to modify
([DeclType].[DeclarationNumber].All,
Measures.[Sum of Need Declaration10])
to calculate the sum for each of them?

2. I need to populate SSRS report with this query. Is it possible to get flattened dataset from this query? Ideal soultion would be set like 
(OrganizationKey, OrganizationName, DeclCount_X, SubCount_X, SumOfNeed_X) where X=1..10.

Comment: To flatten the result, you would need to define a new measure member for each combination of Declaration number and original measure that you have. using the tuple syntax, e. g. `([DeclType].[DeclarationNumber].[typename1], [Measures].[DeclCount])`. Then you would list all these measures in your column list.